# Extending ext4 linux partition kali linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

Okay so I was using windows 10 prior to switching to Kali Linux. I have a 500GB hard drive out of which I gave 70GB to Linux. I dual booted Linux with Windows 10.

So now I wanted to completely delete Windows 10 and give all of my drive space to Linux. I deleted the two partitions I had on Windows using gparted. Now I have about 397GB of unallocated space. But I can't extend the partition in which I have Linux installed because the unallocated space doesn't show up there.

And one more thing. I have unmounted the partition in which I have Linux installed I booted the live ISO on flash drive and now I am in live session.

Here are the screen shots.

[image: image1]

[image: image1]

Answer (score 0):

Try extending `/dev/sda4` using the 397 GB and then shrink it and see where it lands. If it lands under `/dev/sda4` you can try extending your `ext4` partition.

As you maybe can see you have installed your linux system under an "extended" partition. This is why it doesn't show up.